# dropdown fields are not initially populated when form loads

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a ReactJS page that loads a form into a page with a few input fields and a few dropdown/select fields like this:

```
    ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div id="formHome">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
             ...// all the fields
          </form>
      </div>
      document.getElementById('app_root')
   )
```

The form data is populated from a database.

When the form first loads, all the form fields except the the dropdown/select boxes, are populated.

The dropdown/select boxes are just empty.

But when I click on/click off one of the other input fields, the correct values from the database suddenly appear in the dropdown option list.

I am not sure what mechanism is causing this.

I have no code that handles blur or change events, just the onSubmit handler that sends the data to a database.

My onSubmit looks like this:

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
   axios({
     method: "PUT",
     url: "api/gameData/" + values.id,
     data: JSON.stringify(values),
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
       }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error.response);
       }).then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
       });
```

Is there a way to figure out what is going on so that I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the react devtools?

Comment: @DerekPollard  Good idea!  So I just did, the select/dropdown components are showing the correct values in the dev tools.  When I click on then off another form input, the data shown in the dev tools section remains the same, but the correct select/dropdown options suddenly appear in the form as displayed on the web page.

Comment: I think we're going to need more code to further help; can you provide a more complete code sample?